# Iterating through a map and deleting an element that was dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, sdl

Here is my code:

```
void SurfaceManager::SurfaceManagerDelete()
{
    for(map<string,SurfaceManager*>::iterator Iter = SurfaceList.begin(); Iter != SurfaceList.end(); ++Iter)
    {
        delete (*Iter).second;

        (Iter) = SurfaceList.erase(Iter);
    }

   SurfaceList.clear();
}
```

Why does this cause several memory leaks when I scan it with VLD? I know it has something to do with the way I'm deleting the memory from an element specifically this line "(Iter) = SurfaceList.erase(Iter);", however I would like to know why, and how I'm supposed to properly delete elements from the list.

Comment: Use smart pointers and your question will become obsolete.

Comment: In modern C++ you **never** use `delete`. At all. You have no excuse since VS2010 provides `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the ++Iter in the for-loop. That's because

```
(Iter) = SurfaceList.erase(Iter);
```

already updates Iter to point to the element after the erased one, like an increment.

So the ++Iter then skips another element, effectively you end up deleting every other element!

Comment: Which is why it creates several memory leaks.
I see now, This makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @YasinKhalil You're welcome. And don't forget that std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr might very well simplify the solution by not requiring you to ever call 'delete' manually...

Answer (score 1):

You must take care to operate on the correct iterators. In your case, you are skipping one iterator because of the `++Iter` in the `for` loop, and you'll sometimes end up calling `++` on the end iterator.

The usualy mutating associative container loop goes like this:

```
for (auto it = m.cbegin(); it != m.cend() /* not hoisted */; /* no increment */)
{
    if (delete_condition)
    {
        // other stuff, like "delete it->second;"
        m.erase(it++);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're disposing of the entire container, don't use `erase` at all:

```
for (auto & p : m) { delete p.second; }

// or alternatively

for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) { delete it->second; }

m.clear();
```

(I would like to note that I've only found uses for `clear()` on a container very rarely. Normally in C++, you scope your objects tightly so that they only live for the minimal necessary time, and when you need a new map, you just create a new one, rather than clearing and re-using one which lives too long.)

Comment: I don't understand this syntax "for (auto p : m)".

Comment: @YasinKhalil: it's a range base loop, new in C++11. It's similar to the more verbose `for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)`, where `p` is `*it`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however this worked  `for (auto it = SurfaceList.begin(); it != SurfaceList.end(); ++it) { delete (*it).second; }
 SurfaceList.clear();`   and this `for (auto p : m)` didn't work, I kept getting the "cannot deduce auto type" error.

Comment: Well, `m` is just a name for the map I made up. You'd have to say `for (auto & p : SurfaceList)` (put the reference in, too, I had forgotten that one).

Comment: Yeah, haha I knew it was just a letter you used. I meant that the syntax `for(auto p : m)` was giving me errors. `for (auto p : SurfaceList)` is what i actually used. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @KerrekSB He's not calling ++ on an invalid iterator, he's re-assigning the iterator with the result of erase(), so the iterator already points at the following element, and the ++ skips the next one (which is really evil if it alread was at end()).

Comment: @SegFault: Ah, of course. In that case he's calling `++` on the `end()` iterator. Thanks!